# Toggle hide ID on click function, show when function toggled again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I need some help with this: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2gshauf/).
The problem is, that i would like the button to display:none, or in some way hide, whenever the class .active isOpened - if that makes any sense?

If you look at my JSfiddle, i need the button top/right to dissapear, when ever the slide-out menu/box is out.

```
 var isOpened = false;
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in') {
        $("#slide-in").removeClass("active");
        isOpened = false;
      } else if(!isOpened && e.target.id=='button'){
        $("#slide-in").addClass("active");
        isOpened = true;
      }
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide and show the button respectively in the condition.

```
    var isOpened = false;
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in') {
        $("#slide-in").removeClass("active");
        isOpened = false;
        $("#button").show();
      } else if(!isOpened && e.target.id=='button'){
        $("#slide-in").addClass("active");
        isOpened = true;
        $("#button").hide();
      }
    });
```

Here's the [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/s2gshauf/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Js with:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    $('#slide-in').addClass('active');
  if($('#slide-in').not(':hidden').length > 0)
    $('#button').hide();
});

$('#slide-in').click(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('active');
  $('#button').show();
});
```

When you klick the button your Menu left fades in and the button will disappear.
When you click then on the open menu the menu will close and the button will appear again.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Joel_Jaun/d8w08sk3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. The only problem I see is that if you click on a element within the `slide-in` with other id, it will close your div too. But I don't know if its the dessire beahviour.

Here is an examle of what I'm saying:

```js
var isOpened = false;
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in') {
      $("#slide-in").removeClass("active");
      isOpened = false;
    } else if(!isOpened && e.target.id=='button'){
      $("#slide-in").addClass("active");
      isOpened = true;
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#slide-in {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    box-shadow: inset -10px 0 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition-property: margin-left;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-property: margin-left;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -300px;
}

#slide-in.active {
   margin-left: 0;
}

#button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="slide-in">
  <button id="eee">
    deded
  </button>
</div>
```

If you click the button dedede close the div. You can fix it with this code:

```js
var isOpened = false;
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in' && !$(e.target).closest('#slide-in').is('div')) {
      $("#slide-in").removeClass("active");
      isOpened = false;
    } else if(!isOpened && e.target.id=='button'){
      $("#slide-in").addClass("active");
      isOpened = true;
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#slide-in {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    box-shadow: inset -10px 0 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition-property: margin-left;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-property: margin-left;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -300px;
}

#slide-in.active {
   margin-left: 0;
}

#button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="slide-in">
  <button id="eee">
    deded
  </button>
</div>
```